# Recyclerview set clipChildren

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, recyclerview-layout

How can I allow the children of my `RecyclerView` to draw on each other like children of a `ViewGroup` normally do with `clipChildren="false"`?

I use `CardViews` in my `RecyclerView` and I want the shadow of one `CardView` to cover the `CardView` below.

Comment: use elevation in cardview

Comment: yeah, thats what i do, but the elevation of a cardview is linked to its view, so it isn't drawn on other views unless clipChildren is set which brings us back to my question

Comment: So did you find the solution?

Answer (score 7):

you can try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```